# PHP Symfony2 Redirect with POST data

Tags: php, symfony, redirect, post

I am implementing a payment gateway in my e-commerce application. On success/failure, it returns a JSON response on a given URL(for both success and failure). Depending on the state, I have to redirect it to success and failure URLs with POST data. I need two different URLs(success & failure) for analytic reasons.

My project is on Symfony 2.0

Now I know Symfony has a way to redirect.

```
$this->redirect($this->generateUrl('pg_success'));
```

But I cannot send POST data this way.

Also, there is a way to call another action using forward and send arguments

```
$this->forward('DemoBundle:Checkout:pgsuccess', $_POST);
```

But this does not change the URL in the address bar.

Is there a way to perform a URL redirect through which I can send arguments?
Or some similar solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not possible to redirect with POST data. You have following options to solve your problem:

1. Redirect with GET parameters.

   $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('pg_success', $_POST));
2. Use forward with arguments.

   $this->forward('DemoBundle:Checkout:pgsuccess', $_POST);

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#forwarding-to-another-controller

3. Simply use session to pass data to the redirect target.

Before redirect:

```
$session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
$session->set('data' => $_POST);
```

After redirect:

```
$session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
$data = $session->get('data');
```

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using sessions to save and retrieve the data.

Comment: In SF there is a dedicated method for accessing $_POST params which should be used instead of accessing PHP vars directly: $data = $request->request->all().
 From symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/introduction.html "**HttpFoundation component replaces these default PHP global variables and functions by an object-oriented layer**".
 Besides $this->getRequest() is depracated.

Answer (score -2):

to set session :

```html
$session->set('data' , $_POST);
```